# how can we use maven in pure spring project?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I know that Maven is a widely used build automation and project management tool.

It is often used to manage dependencies, build projects, and download all dependencies for us. I am wondering that can't we use maven in pure spring project so that we don't have to download all the dependencies manually and add them on class path??

I just added the dependency in xml file.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

it's not working do I have to add something else?

Comment: Save time by generating the project with Spring official tool, select maven and the dependencies you want, that will give you a project you can check its pom.xml and understand it https://start.spring.io/

Comment: If you don't want to use Spring Boot, you would need to define versions and possibly more dependencies.

Comment: what do you mean by "pure spring"? does that mean not using spring-boot? I doubt that because you're using a spring-boot-starter. please post a [mcve] so people can reproduce the issue and provide a real error message or other description of what happens ("not working" doesn't cut it). the advice to use the spring starter is good, there is also https://spring.io/guides if you want to look at small but complete and running projects.

Comment: I never did a Spring project without maven.